# Positioning of Tab Bar in iOS 5 and iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, tabbar

I am making app in iphone. I had used the tab bar. My app support both iOS 5 and iOS 6.

But if i make app screens in Retina 4 than my tab is not in position. The screenshot is given below

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you mean iOS instead of iPhone :)

Comment: are you saying about iOS 5 and iOS6

Comment: Yes i am saying about ios 5 and ios 6

Comment: iOS 5 and iOS 6 has nothing to do with iPhone 4 or iPhone 5 height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Autolayout check if the tabbar has a constraint to be on the bottom. 
If not check wether the tabbar is "fixed" on the bottom with the autoresize feature of your View.

This is the Autoresize Feature but not correct for your tabbar your tabbar would need the bottom restriction
[image]